# How to get all href values in an html page using PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink, href

I want to get the value of href links on a html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with PHP.  You need to use JavaScript to get the value of href links on an html page:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=0, l = document.links; i<l.length; i++) {
  arr.push(l[i].href);
}
```

You can then do an AJAX Post to send the links to your server which PHP can then process.

Comment: Thank you the problem is solved.